# How to Maybe-ify this recursive code?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I have this snippet of Haskell code that computes a cost function for least squares regression:

```
cost :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]] -> Double
cost [[]] [[]] = 0
cost ((x:xs):xss) ((y:ys):yss) = (x-y)^2 + cost [xs] [ys] + cost xss yss
cost _ _ = 0

print (cost [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] [[1,3,3],[4,6,6]]) -- 2.0
```

This works fine, but now I'd like to have a return type of `Maybe Double`. How could I do that? Let's say the last case `cost _ _ = Nothing`. The result should be `Just 2.0` for the inputs given here.

Comment: Not sure why you're dealing with `[[Double]]` values. Is the inner `[Double]` supposed to represent a point in 3D space? In that case, you should define a custom data type, for more type safety. Your function would also become easier to write.

Comment: @Jubobs This is for N-dimensional vectors. Custom data type is on my list of things to implement!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a case for empty lists, turn all recursive calls into binds, and apply `return` to the final result in each equation. Thus:

```
cost :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]] -> Maybe Double
cost [] [] = return 0
cost [[]] [[]] = return 0
cost ((x:xs):xss) ((y:ys):yss) = do
    c  <- cost [xs] [ys]
    c' <- cost xss yss
    return ((x-y)^2 + c + c')
cost _ _ = Nothing
```

However, the number of cases concerns me. You could consider writing something like this, instead:

```
import Control.Applicative

costBy :: (a -> a -> Maybe Double) -> [a] -> [a] -> Maybe Double
costBy f [] [] = return 0
costBy f (x:xs) (y:ys) = liftA2 (+) (f x y) (costBy f xs ys)
costBy _ _ _ = Nothing

cost' :: [[Double]] -> [[Double]] -> Maybe Double
cost' = costBy (costBy (\x y -> return ((x-y)^2)))
```

Here you do not need the `cost [xs] [ys]` shenanigans to reuse code, rather using polymorphism to get the same shape-checking behavior at both the `[Double]` and `[[Double]]` layers. It is also much more clear that you have covered all the cases of interest, since you are dealing with just one layer of list-iness at a time.

Comment: Great stuff! You have given me a lot to pore over.